# What happens to a queue? (c++)

Tags: c++, qt, static

```
        queue1.h        mainwindow.h
        /               /
        A.h---Mainwindow.cpp
```

A #includes queue1
Mainwidow #includes A
A and MainWindow both need to use one instanse of queue1, so i define it in A like "static queue1 q1;"
Then in A.h i push "A" in a q1, but when i try to output it in mainwindow i get trash. 
When i try to push "mainwindow" inside mainwindow.h and then output it is ok.
I'm using Qt 4.7.0 and win 7.

queue1.h

```
#ifndef QUEUE1_H
#define QUEUE1_H
#include <queue>
#include <string>

class queue1
{
public:
    queue1();
   std::queue<std::string> q;
};

#endif // QUEUE1_H
```

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#include "queue1.h"
static queue1 q1;
class A
{
public:
    A(){q1.q.push("A");}
};

#endif // A_H
```

If you uncomment "q1.q.push("mainwindow");" the program will first output "mainwondow" and then trash. After that queue become empty.

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "a.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //q1.q.push("mainwindow");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->label->setText(q1.q.front().c_str());
    q1.q.pop();


}
```

For this test project i didn't changed mainwindow.h but here it is.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: why cant i output "A", what happens to it and why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` does not mean what you mean it does in this context — it takes away external linkage from a symbol, meaning it will only be visible within a given translation unit. And because you have it in the header, included by two units, there will be two distinct instances of your class — so when you push in A, you push to the queue in A, not the queue in mainwindow.

The solution is to declare the variable as `extern`, and define it in only one translation unit.

```
// in queue1.h
class queue1 { ... };
extern queue1 q1;

// in e.g. queue1.cpp
#include "queue1.h"
queue1 q1;
```

Now both A and mainwindow will use the same queue (of course you need to remove `static queue1 q1;`
 from A.h).

Comment: @Stals: Did you remove that static variable? Rebuild all units, and if the problem persists, use a debugger.

Comment: strange, it doesn't work in this test project but works in a main project... But thanks anyway.

Comment: LOL, i didn't call constructor of A.

Answer (score 0):

Declare q1 as extern, not static.